# Opencart Could not load database driver mmysqli

Tags: mysql, database, opencart2.x

How can I solve this problem, Could not load database driver mmysqli,
I change my host

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because there is no mmysqli driver. 
Easy solution to your problem is to open file: config.php and at DB Driver constant change "mmysqli" to "mysqli", save the file, upload it and you are ready.

Important: Server should have mysqli driver installed to work. If you are using PHP <7.0 then you can also use "mysql". It's recommended to use "mysqli" though.

Cheers!